# Integrating a product of Gaussian kernels

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

If we consider the Gaussian kernel $k(x, y) = \exp(-\frac{\Vert x - y \Vert^2}{2\sigma^2})$, then is it true that...

$$
\int k(x_i, x)k(x_j, x)dx = k(x_i, x_j)
$$

It seems I have seen this before, but I cannot find a proper derivation of it.

Comment: Wait a sec. Are you sure this is true? I scribbled down a few computations and it does not seem to work.

Comment: I added a community wiki with a version of the formula that appears to be correct. You are missing some factors of $\pi$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you for catching my mistake and posting the correct formula. I updated my answer accordingly with some references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE :** The claim in the OP is **not** true and the previous version of this answer based on Moore-Aronszajn theorem is **wrong** (unfortunately I could not delete it as it had been accepted by the OP). Thanks to Giuseppe for the catch !

---

As highlighted in [Giuseppe's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4842321/857384), the correct formula is indeed
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d} k_\sigma(x_1, y)k_\sigma(x_2, y)\, dy= \left(\frac{\pi}{\sigma^2}\right)^\frac{d}{2} k_{\sigma\sqrt2}(x_1, x_2). $$
And a derivation can be found in section 4.2, page 84 of the book [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) by Rasmussen and Williams.

Although it's not as nice as before, we can still connect this result to the theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces : basically if we define the map $\Phi:\mathbb R^d\to L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ by
$$\Phi(x) := \left[t\mapsto\frac{(2 \sigma)^{\frac{d}{2}}}{\pi^{\frac{d}{4}}} e^{- 2 \sigma^2 \lVert x - t \rVert^2}
\right] $$
What we have is that $\Phi$ is a [feature map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Feature_maps) for the Gaussian kernel $k_\sigma$, in the sense that we have
$$k_\sigma(x,y) =\int_{\mathbb R^d} [\Phi(x)](t) \; [\Phi(y)](t) \, d t
 = \left\langle\Phi(x),\Phi(y)\right\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)} $$

for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^d$.

For a proof and more on the representations of the RKHS associated with the Gaussian kernel, one can check [An Explicit Description of the Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces of Gaussian RBF Kernels (2006)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101033442/https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.107&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Steinwart, Hush and Scovel.

Comment: I think this is the right property of the Gaussian kernel to invoke. Is there a probabilistic interpretation of such property? Presumably in terms of Markov processes or something like that, sorry to be so vague. (I don't really remember much about stochastic processes)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro there are some connections indeed but I'm not too familiar with them : for instance if $(X_t)$ is a Gaussian process with covariance $k$, there are sufficient conditions (on the mean of $X_t$) to determine whether the sample paths lie in a certain RKHS $H'\supseteq H$ with probability 1. Look e.g. in section 4 of this paper : [Gaussian Processes and Kernel Methods: A Review on Connections and Equivalences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02582)

Comment: Hmm I am having some second thoughts on (1). You are right that Moore-Aronszajin gives $f(x)=\langle k(x, \cdot), f\rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is *some* scalar product. Who tells us that $\langle f_1, f_2\rangle=\int f_1(y)f_2(y)\, dy$? Say, for example, it might be $\langle f_1, f_2\rangle=\int f_1(y)f_2(y)w(y)\, dy$ for some function $w$. Or something completely different. How can we rule this out?

Comment: you're absolutely right, I made a mistake. Actually the theorem "explictly" gives the inner product associated to the kernel and in this case it is definitely *not* $\langle f_1, f_2\rangle=\int f_1(y)f_2(y)\, dy$ (see wikipedia). I will delete my answer and try to think of something else.

Answer (score 2):

The Gaussian kernel has its name from the fact, that it is annihilated by the diffusion operator with time  $\sigma =t$

$$k(t,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \ t}} \ e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 t}}$$

$$\partial_t k(t,x) - \frac{1}{2}\partial_{x,x} k(t,x)=0, \quad k(0,x) = \delta (x)$$
by
$$\partial_t k(t,x)  = (\frac{x^2}{t^2} - \frac{1}{2 t}) \  k(t,x), \quad  \partial_x  k(t,x)  = -\frac{x}{t}\ k(t,x)$$

The Gaussian kernel  as solution  to the diffusion equation is the probability density at time t of a random walk starting at x=0, at t=0 in the limit of a continous Brownian motion, the Wiener process.

Your integral is a convolution integral

$$ (f\star g)(x-z)) = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x-y)\ g(y-z) \ dy  \to { (y-z=u) }\to \int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x-z-u)\ g(u) \ du  $$

Convolution integrals transform to products of their Fourier transform (up to factors of $\sqrt{2\pi}$)

$$\int_{-\infty} ^\infty f(x-u)\ g(u) \ du  =\int \int \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \hat f(k) \hat g(m)  e^{i (k(x-u)+m u)} du \ dk \ dm  = \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \hat f(k) \hat g(k) e^{i k x} dk $$

The Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian with inverse variance, leading to  convoluted Gaussians with sum a variances.

Semantics: a Gaussian with variance $t$ is the distribution of a Wiener process $$W_t = \int_0^t dW_s$$ up to time t.

A Wiener process $ W_s, s>0$ with the start distribution of $W_t, t>0$  has  Gaussian distribution with variance $t+s$ by the fundamental solution of the diffusion equation $$\partial_t f(t,x) -\partial_{x,x} f(t,x)=0, \quad  t>0 ,  \quad f(0,x)=\delta(x) \quad \longrightarrow \quad f(t,x)= \theta(t)\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \ t} \  e^{-\frac{x ^2}{2 t}}$$.

$$\partial_t f(t,x) -\frac{1}{2}\ \partial_{x,x} f(t,x)=0, \quad  t>0 ,  \quad f(0,x)=g(x) \quad \longrightarrow \quad f(t,x) =\theta(t)\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \ t} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \  e^{-\frac{(x-\xi)^2}{2 t}}\ g(\xi)\ d\xi $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but actually I don't see the final connection to my question (I think I am missing something). Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: I think this one is a different property of the Gaussian kernel. In this answer, there is a parameter $t>0$ and this argument (neatly) shows that the Gaussian kernel is a semigroup in $t$. However, in the original question, there is no $t$. It is a question about the spatial variables $x, y \in \mathbb R^n$ only.

Comment: No, its a question about addition of variances in a convolution of Gussians. Can, of course  be calculated directly by substitutions $$\frac{\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}-\frac{(z-y)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \, dy}{2 \pi  \sigma ^2}$$

$$\fbox{$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-z)^2}{4 \sigma ^2}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}\text{ if }\Re\left(\sigma ^2\right)\geq 0$}$$
with the double variance

Comment: @RolandF: Oh really? Great, this looks like exactly the "probabilistic interpretation" I am asking for in [the comment to the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840190/integrating-a-product-of-gaussian-kernels/4840869?noredirect=1#comment10310264_4840869)

Comment: I see now, thank you for the added context.

Answer (score 2):

I think the formula does not hold as is, there is a couple of missing factors: there is a $\pi^{\frac{d}{2}}$ in the right-hand side, a $\sigma^d$ in the denominator and the $k$ in the right-hand side has a different $\sigma$.

More precisely, letting $k_\sigma(x, y):=\exp\left( -\frac{|x-y|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$, the correct formula should be $$ \int_{\mathbb R^d} k_\sigma(x_1, y)k_\sigma(x_2, y)\, dy= \left(\frac{\pi}{\sigma^2}\right)^\frac{d}{2} k_{\sigma\sqrt2}(x_1, x_2).$$

Comment: Thanks for the great discussion here. I think this actually might answer a follow up question I would have to the accepted answer... Basically, the kernel which is reproduced is "a" kernel, but not necessarily "the" kernel since the parameters of the kernel function have changed on the RHS, right?

Comment: I also liked this discussion, thanks for sparking it. Anyway, well, you answered your own question: if you wanted a formula like $k\ast k = k$ then no, this is not true. (There are essentially no convolution kernels that can satisfy this, as you can see via the Fourier transform).